# How to define filter env-entry in Grails 6.0.0, resources.groovy?

Tags: spring-mvc, grails

I am uplifting an older Grails 1.3.7 application to Grails 6.0.0. In older project under `src/templates/war/web.xml` oAuth filters were defined, along with env-entry, as shown below :

```
<filter>
    <description>Filtering for the service</description>
    <filter-name>AuthN</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.oAuthReportingFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>oauth-validator</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.oAuthValidateFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

...

<env-entry>
    <description>The OAuth Service API endpoint URL</description>
    <env-entry-name>config/oauth</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>https://com.example.url</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  </env-entry>
  <env-entry>
    <description>The system account ID for accessing the OAuth Service API</description>
    <env-entry-name>config/oauth/accountId</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>654657-7678-78-786ghjhj</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  </env-entry>
  <env-entry>
    <description>The system account secret for accessing the OAuth Service API</description>
    <env-entry-name>config/oauth/key</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>ffyugu76hjg</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
  </env-entry>
```

In Grails 6.0.0, I read in official documentation that we need to define filters in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy something like this :

```
beans = { 
  authN(FilterRegistrationBean) {
        filter = bean(oAuthReportingFilter)
        urlPatterns = ['/*']
        // we want all other Grails filters to have loaded first
        order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 5
    }
}
```

When I am registering my filters like above how do I define, env-entry values, as on env-entry values my filter initialisation depends. I am using Grails 6.0.0 with embedded tomcat.